# views filter show node only one time?

Tags: views

I have a view, and i filter the nodes based on a list of tags. If one node has more than one matching tag, it's displayed more than once. Can you filter those out? Want to display them only once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view under "advanced", next to "query settings" click "settings" and check "Distinct". This option makes sure every node only gets displayed once.

Comment: Could you upvote my answer so that people know this asnwer is legit?

Comment: @user3122986 when ever you ask a question if you got the right answer please vote up.

Comment: "vote up requires 15 reputation?"

Answer (score 0):

Click SQL settings in your view:

[image]

Select Distinct:

[image]